# I can't make a single project in django in my vs code after installing all the extensions

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBa5Z.png)

I have installed python extension as well as installed django also in my VS code still I can't make any project in it.It's showing the following error

Comment: Your going to have to be a bit more detailed than that. Are you opening up a virtual environment? Are you installing django into that env are you running all the commands properly? Please rephrase your question to include all that you have done so that we don't have to play 20 questions with you.

Comment: Looks like Django is not installed. Maybe you followed a tutorial that used virtual environment and you forgot to activate it?